# How does one find the lowest ancestor with a descendant leaf node with some label?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, ancestor, lowest-common-ancestor

#### The problem

Given a rooted tree with **n** nodes, where all leaves are labelled from a set of labels. Build a datastructure which, given a leaf node, **a** and a label **l**, can find the lowest ancestor, **u**, of **a**, where **u** has at least one descendant with label **l**.

#### Linear Space / Linear Time approach

- Start at leaf **a**
- Examine all siblings of **a**

  - If a sibling has label **l** find the lowest-common-ancestor between **a** and that sibling.
  - Otherwise continue to parents
- If all leaf-nodes descending from parents are not labelled **l**, continue to the grandparents and check their leaf-node descendants.
- Continue recursively checking greater-grandparents and all their descendant leaf-nodes until an **l**-labelled descendant is found.

This has time complexity **O(n)** and space complexity **O(n)**.

---

Is there a faster way to do this with linear space complexity? Perhaps by preproccessing the tree somehow? **l** and **a** are not fixed so the pre-processing has to be flexible.

The lowest common ancestor can be found in constant time using RMQ via Eulerian-Tour.

Keep in mind the tree is not balanced or sorted in any way.

Comment: If `a` and `l` are siblings, then by definition they share the same parent, which is the lowest common ancestor. What do you mean here by "sibling" of `a`? Also, do your nodes have parent pointers?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, if **a** and some node with label **l** are siblings, then yes, the parent would be the lowest common ancestor. I just used "lower common ancestor" so that it would apply for any two leaf nodes.

Comment: If you're willing to spend the time and memory in preprocessing, you can create a lookup table that gives you O(1) query. The memory requirement would be O(m^2), where m is the number of leaf nodes.

Comment: Ah yes, however the algorithm is intended for arbitrary trees with no additional data structures. So the pre-processing would factor the time complexity. Thanks though!

Comment: If you want to do a single query against a tree, then your worst case time complexity is O(n), because you potentially have to look at every node. And worst case space complexity is O(n) because in a degenerate tree you potentially have to maintain a path that contains every node in the tree. I don't think you can improve the complexity, given the constraints you've outlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with **O(log(n)^3)** time complexity and **O(n log(n))** space complexity.

Let `L` be the list of labels that you encounter on the Eulerian Path. You build a Segment Tree with this list, and store in each node of the tree the set of labels appearing in the corresponding segment.
Then you can check in **O(log(n)^2)** time, if a label appears in a subtree via a range query in the segment tree.

To find the correct parent, you can do a binary search. E.g. something similar to binary lifting. Which will add another factor of **log(n)**.

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way to cram this method into linear space complexity?

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

So, now I found a better solution:

The idea is the following:
the further two nodes appear in the Euler Path, the higher their LCA is.
I.e. `index(a) < index(b) < index(c)` => `dist_to_root(LCA(a, b)) >= dist_to_root(LCA(a, c))`.

This means that you only have to compute the LCA of **a** and the first node after **a** with the label **l** in the path, and the LCA of **a** and the last node before **a** with the label **l** in the path.

One of them will give the optimal solution to the problem.

To find these two indices efficiently, create a list of indices for each label, and perform a binary search in **O(log n)**.

Memory complexity is **O(n)**.

Comment: But doesn't creating a list of indices take O(n) time?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, but you only need to do it once during preprocessing.

Comment: Note that LCA = "lowest common ancestor:, and "Euler Path" = "Euler Tour representation of the tree" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique), which also enables transforming the LCA problem in to a "range minimum query", which you can do in O(log N) as well. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-lca-in-binary-tree-using-rmq/  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, I know. It can even be done in O(1). The OP already wrote that he know how to do this task, so I didn't explained in my answer.

Comment: @user38034 Thanky you! I'll give this a shot. Yes, by calculating the Eulerian Path and BST in pre-processing, the query can be done in **O(log n)** time complexity.

Considering your reply, this could perhaps be pushed down to **O(log log n)** using [y-fast-tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie).

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny Just a reminder: here on Stackoverflow there is this concept of upvotes and accepting answers, which usually means a lot more than a thank you :-P